# Change shape of all items inside \begin{itemize}

Tags: fonts, lists

I currently have this:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textsc{foo}
  \item \textsc{bar}
\end{itemize}
```

Is there a way to avoid writing `\textsc` multiple times? I.e. change the shape of all items only inside that environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of ways of achieving this:

1. Using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\AtBeginEnvironment`:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\scshape}
   ```
2. Via [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `before` key-value:

   ```
   \usepackage{enumitem}
   \setlist[itemize]{before=\scshape}
   ```
3. Declare a new environment `scitemize` and use that instead:

   ```
   \newenvironment{scitemize}
     {\begin{itemize}\scshape}
     {\end{itemize}}
   ```
4. Update the existing `itemize` to always include `\scshape`:

   ```
   \let\olditemize\itemize
   \renewcommand{\itemize}{\olditemize\scshape}
   ```

Comment: I actually ended up just using this `begin{itemize}\scshape\item Foo...`.